# How to create UV and texture for egg shaped model

Tags: texturing, uv

I've searched and toyed with this for quite some time. I have a penguin who's body is egg shaped and I'm trying to do the UV and texture for it. If I use projection from view then it comes out nearly OK except for a few areas (see image). The problem is that it seems no matter how I change the UV's vertices I can't fix the offending areas. 
I'm hoping someone can help.
Thanks!

[image: lower edge gets weird]

Front view looks fine
[image: front view looks ok]

Comment: How many subsurf levels have you set? Try to increase susurf level.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't want to use subsurf because it is an asset for a game.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reproject your texture upon a catmull-clark subdivided version of the mesh with the subdivide UVs option **disabled**.

This way you should be able to have more faces (and so a higher projecting accuracy), while maintaining the same UV islands.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

In my testfile this process was able to mitigate the effect of the distortion.

Once reprojected the texture, you can obiuvsly delete the modifier and keep your vertex count untouched.

Comment: thanks, but that's really not making much of a difference. That edge should continuously bow out. The white are is also mostly egg-shaped. I've tried up to 6 subdivisions. Any further and Blender is unusable.This is way harder to do than I expected :(

Answer (score 0):

Make a higher subsurfed model and bake the normals onto the low-poly model. That should smooth out those distortions for you and keep your vertex budget level.